# SKBitmap to Image.ImageSource on MacOS

Tags: macos, xamarin.forms, skiasharp, uno-platform

I'm writing an Uno application using SkiaSharp in VS2019, Windows and Mac.

I have an Image, defined in Xaml, that I need to display.

```
            SKBitmap writeableBitmap = new SKBitmap(width, height);
            await UpdateImage(writeableBitmap);
#if NETFX_CORE  // Uno-ese for "Windows" 
            graphBox.Source = SkiaSharp.Views.UWP.UWPExtensions.ToWriteableBitmap(writeableBitmap);
#else
            graphBox.Source = writeableBitmap;
#endif
```

The #else bit doesn't work in Uno/Xamarin Mac, but neither does the UWP extension, and the SkiaSharp.Views.Mac.Extensions doesn't have an equivalent.

I can create a bitmap stream with, e.g.,

```
SKData pngData = SKImage.FromBitmap(writableBitmap);.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100);
```

But I haven't figured out how to load that into an ImageSource or BitmapSource, which is what the Image (windows.ui.xaml.media.image) expects.

How can I get from SKBitmap to Xamarin-friendly Image?

Answer (score 0):

Well... here's the answer.  WriteableBitmap is BGRA-encoded, not RGB encoded, so your Skia bitmap also should be.  In Windows, it doesn't have to be because the conversion works, but that's not an option on MacOS.

```
SKBitmap workBitmap = new SKBitmap(width, height, SKColorType.Bgra8888, SKAlphaType.Opaque);
// Do your drawing, etc., here.
var bitmap = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap(width, height);
using (Stream stream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream()) 
{ stream.Write(workBitmap.Bytes); } 
// Now you can use bitmap as the ImageSource
graphBox.Source = bitmap;
```